# Lightning Component Error, - Init Event : Error during init [Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined]

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events

I am developing a new Lightning Component with custom Event. 
But I am getting Following Error while loading the Page in browser Preview.

> Sorry to interrupt This page has an error. You might just need to
>   refresh it. Error during init [Cannot read property 'apply' of
>   undefined]

I have the following code .

1) Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" > 

   <aura:registerEvent name="change" type="NBLight:valuesChange" />


    <aura:attribute name="principal" type="double" default="10"/>
    <aura:attribute name="rate" type="double" default="10"/>
    <aura:attribute name="year" type="double" default="10"/>

    <aura:attribute name="monthlyEMI" type="double" />

    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.principal}" action="{!calculateMonthlyPayment}" />
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.rate}" action="{!calculateMonthlyPayment}" />
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.year}" action="{!calculateMonthlyPayment}" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!NBLight.doInit}"/>   

    <div>
        <ui:inputNumber label="Enter Principal " value="{!v.principal}"/>
        <ui:inputNumber label="Enter Rate of Interest " value="{!v.rate}"/>
        <ui:inputNumber label="Enter Duration in years " value="{!v.year}"/>
     <h2> Monthly Payment :: <ui:outputCurrency value="{!v.monthlyEMI}" />
     </h2>

    </div>
</aura:component>
```

2)  Controller

```
({
    doInit :  function(component, event, helper) {

        setTimeout(function(){
           helper.calculateMonthlyPayment(component);
        }
    },
    calculateMonthlyPayment : function(component, event, helper) {
         alert("hello there!"); 
            console.log("Hi nitin");
        helper.calculateMonthlyPayment(component);
          console.log("By nitin");
    }

})
```

3) Helper

```
({
    calculateMonthlyPayment : function(component) {

        //calculate monthly emi
        var principal = component.get("v.principal");
        var year = component.get("v.year");
        var rate = component.get("v.rate");
        var monthlyEMI = principal * rate * year ;
        component.set("v.monthlyEMI",monthlyEMI);
        console.log("Nitin Items has changed");
        console.log("old value: " + evt.getParam("oldValue"));
        console.log("current value: " + evt.getParam("value"));

        // Fire the change Event 
        var event = $A.get("e.NBLight:valuesChange");
        event.setParams({"principal": principal,"year":year,"rate":rate, "monthlyEMI":monthlyEMI});
        event.fire();
    }
})
```

4) valueschange Event

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" description="Value change Event " >
<aura:attribute name="principal" type="double"/>
<aura:attribute name="year" type="double"/>
<aura:attribute name="rate" type="double"/>
</aura:event>
```

5) Application

```
<aura:application >
 <h1> Welcome To Automatic Mortgage Calculate</h1>
     <NBLight:SimpleMortgageCalcComponentAutomatic />
 <h2> Thank You !!!</h2>

</aura:application>
```

Please Let me know why this error is coming and how to correct it.

Thanks

Comment: Where have you defined the event? To bind an action you have to use the following syntax: `c.controllerMethodName` not  `component.methodName OR methodName`

Comment: I have created 1 New Lightning event named "valuesChange" .

Comment: Can u be more specific about line no and which file u r mentioning. ?
NBLight is my  namespace .
 <aura:registerEvent name="change" type="NBLight:valuesChange" />

Comment: `<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!NBLight.doInit}"/>` and `<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.year}" action="{!calculateMonthlyPayment}" />`

Comment: @itzmukeshy7  can u plz elaborate. I am struck

Comment: The all 3 change handler action must be `{!c.calculateMonthlyPayment}`

Comment: And to get the error source put your JS code inside `try...catch` construct.

Comment: What was the issue here... ?